# mongo-java-driver how to use string id reflection ObjectId

Tags: java, c#, mongodb

in mongodb：

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5a1e8e10cf40cb2b6b08112f")
}
```

in C#, i can use this (ps:i need to setting string ID,not ObjectID)

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    public class ElapsedTimeLog : IEntity<string>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 主键ID
        /// </summary>
        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string ID { get; set; }
     }
```

but in java，i don't know how to do,
i didn't found @BsonRepresentation or like something

when i write like this,  it error

```
public class User_ObjectID implements EntityStringKey {
    //
    @BsonId
    private String id;

    //#region 
    public String getId(){return id;}

    public void setId(String id){this.id = id;}
    //#endregion
}
```

Error Message：
An exception occurred when decoding using the AutomaticPojoCodec.
Decoding into a 'User_ObjectID' failed with the following exception:

```
Failed to decode '_id'. readString can only be called when CurrentBSONType is STRING, not when CurrentBSONType is OBJECT_ID.

A custom Codec or PojoCodec may need to be explicitly configured and registered to handle this type.
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using String for id, You need to use ObjectId class. This class maps _id of mongoDB to Java

```
private ObjectId id;
```

After Getting the object, you can get the _id String by -

```
id.toString();
```

Comment: thank you very much，
i now this write，but i need to use string ID，like C#

Comment: i have updated the answer. Please up-vote answer if found useful. :)

Comment: but the "User_ObjectID" is entity，
and "mongo-java-driver" use pojo to serialize